# How to recognize VT-100 escape sequences when reading a file

Tags: emacs, vt100

I have a file (output from a program) that includes VT-100 escape sequences (colors, bold face, etc.). When I open the file in Fundamental mode, the escape sequences appear as are, and are not interpreted. How can display the file with the VT-100 sequences recognized as colors, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19494/how-to-colorize-text-in-emacs

For example: put the following in your emacs init file:

```
(define-derived-mode fundamental-ansi-mode fundamental-mode "fundamental ansi"
  "Fundamental mode that understands ansi colors."
  (require 'ansi-color)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

then run `M-x fundamental-ansi-mode` on the buffer with the escape sequences.

Comment: This works mostly well, but it modifies the buffer.  That'd be okay for my personal use case, except that I like to hit a random key and then `y` to revert the buffer.  Also, auto-revert-mode is probably unusable.  Any idea on how to fix these problems?  For now I'm adding undo to the list of keystrokes.

Comment: Also, I find the following helpful for not having to manually enter fundamental-ansi-mode:


(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.log\\'" . fundamental-ansi-mode) auto-mode-alist))